# How can I extend the default constructor for an object using MongoMapper?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

I just started using MongoMapper to manage nested models in a Sinatra app. In this particular case, I just need to check one of the fields when an EmbeddedDocument is initialized, and add a leading slash if one isn't already there.

My idea was to write a check in the initialize method that will take care of it, except writing my own initialize will completely override the default, whereas I want to use the default with my own code added on. I've been trying to find some resources on extending MongoMappers constructors, using super, or anything like that but I haven't found much.

Even if this isn't the best way to solve my current problem (ensuring a leading slash on a String field), I'd also like to know how to extend MongoMapper's default constructor, just for future reference. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I found the MongoMapper Validation docs that solve my current issue of the leading slash.
http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/validations.html

Still curious about the constructor extension though...

Answer (score 1):

The `initialize` method MongoMapper gives you is in a module, not defined directly on your class.  That means that if you define your `initialize` method, MM's method is still available to you with `super`.

```
def initialize(*args)
  super
  # do your own stuff here
end
```

MongoMapper's internal plugins uses that pattern extensively. Each plugin sets up its own concerns on initialization, then calls `super`.